# Set imageview from array reference?

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, drawable, android-imageview

I'll keep this simple.  I want to set an `ImageView` in an `AlertDialog` to an image in an array of `Drawables`  The image that I would like to set to the `ImageView` can be retrieved by accessing the mImages[position].

Here is a brief explanation (complete explanation below):
In short- I need a way to pass an image from my main activity to a dialog then on Cancel `dismiss` the dialog and on confirm set the system wallpaper (to the image passed from the main activity) then `finish();` the activity.

Here's a complete explanation:

The user is presented with a `Gallery` and an `ImageView` above the `Gallery` that shows a larger preview of the image that has focus in the `Gallery`.

The images displayed in the `Gallery` are setup using:

```
        // setup wallpaper array
private void findWallpapers() {
    mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);
    mImages = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);

    final Resources resources = getResources();
    final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

    addWallpapers(resources, packageName, R.array.wallpapers);
}

// setup array defining all wallpapers & define thumbnails
private void addWallpapers(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
    final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
    for (String extra : extras) {
        int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
        if (res != 0) {
            final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra + "_small",
                    "drawable", packageName);

            if (thumbRes != 0) {
                mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                mImages.add(res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After "Set Wallpaper" `Button` is pressed, an `AlertDialog` should open with another preview of the image that had focus in the `Gallery`.  The `AlertDialog` will contain a `TextView` with instructions, the preview of the image we are proposing to set as the wallpaper, an "Okay" `Button` and a "Cancel" `Button`.  Pressing the "Okay" `Button` will set the image from the `ImageView` preview as the system wallpaper via an `InputStream`.

Thanks again!

```
    private void selectWallpaper(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select Wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    if (mIsWallpaperSet) {
        return;
    }

    mIsWallpaperSet = true;

    Context context = this;
    // CharSequence text = "Wallpaper Set!";
    // int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(
            mImages.get(position));
            final Dialog accept = new Dialog(context);
    accept.setContentView(R.layout.confirm);
    accept.setTitle("Please Confirm");
    TextView instructions = (TextView) accept.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    instructions.setText("Would you like to set this as your wallpaper?");
    ImageView wallpreview = (ImageView) accept
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    wallpreview.createFromStream(stream, "test");
    // SETUP cancel (no btn) listener
    Button cancelbtn = (Button) accept.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            accept.dismiss();
        }
    });
    // SETUP Yes Btn listener
    Button okbtn = (Button) accept.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    okbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // dismiss being used as placeholder, actually setting wallpaper
            // will be added
            accept.dismiss();
        }
    });
    accept.show();
}

{
    ;
}
```

Comment: are you still facing the issue

Comment: Yes, the first solution did not solve the issue.  I will edit my question to better explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the layout inflator to inflate your alert dialog layout and assign it to the View of the alert dialog in your main activity. You can use findViewById() to set the onClickListeners listeners for those buttons. That will ensure that your onClickListener can see mImages.

```
final ArrayList<Integer> mImages=new ArrayList<Integer>();
final ImageView v=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

AlertDialog d=new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
d.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogView,findViewById(R.id.ROOT_LAYOUT_IN_XML_ID),false));

((ImageView)d.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID)).setImageResource(mImages.get(?));

((Button)d.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    d.dismiss();
});
((Button)d.findViewById(R.id.acceptButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    v.setImageResource(mImages.get(?));
    d.dismiss();
});
```

Comment: are you suggesting I use the alert dialog builder vs a completely custom one? Just curious if that makes any difference.  Thanks!  Accepted answer.

Comment: When tools are presented to you, why not used them? So, yes, I am suggesting that. Welcome!

Comment: this did not solve my problem.  inflate does not accept (int, alertDialog, boolean).  I think that you may have also misunderstood my question.  I will edit it to better explain

Comment: My answer will work fine for what you want to do. I am editing it to include setting the preview wallpaper inside the dialogView, however you will have to obtain that image using your own methods. Also, please use your head. If the code I wrote off the top of my head isn't perfect, use Eclipse's (or whichever IDE's) features to figure it out yourself. Or, use the docs. Furthermore, you are right, I slightly mistook inflate(). It needs to be supplied with a subclass of ViewGroup. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the main problem I am having is coming up with a method to pass the image to the dialog.  I have no problem with setting up the dialog, getting it to display, and implementing the onclicklicteners.  Therefore, I am not going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: What is the contents of the mImages list?

Comment: mImages is an array list of all the images I want the gallery to display.  mThumbs is the same image, just the smaller thumbnail that scrolls in the gallery.

Comment: Of course, but what exactly is the data? Bytes? ID of the resource (R.id.imageName)? Be specific.

Comment: My bad, I see you have specified that. It's the resource ID. My answer will still work fine man. I don't know what you are asking. You can just setImageResource of the ImageView in the dialog to the resource ID of the correct image specified in the mImages array.